# Birdwatching in Langkawi Island, Malaysia

Tags: malaysia, activities, outdoor-activities

I plan to go to Langkawi Island in early July, and I would like to try some new things. I have never been snorkeling or bird watching before. There is lots of resources about snorkeling, so I'm all set there. But I also wanted something to do when I'm feeling exhausted, so I thought I could try bird-watching.

### Question

Is there any areas of interest for bird-watching on Langkawi (either the main island or others in the archipelago)? If possible, list what species I can expect to see. I'd like to know which are common and which are rare. Other general tips about bird-watching in Langkawi are welcome too.